# How to get rid of Suspicious call warning on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, button, casting, warnings

In my code I have an `ArrayList<Buttons>` field named `mButtons`.
Each of these buttons invoke (in XML) the same `onClick` function `onButtonClick`.
The function looks like this:

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    int buttonIndex = mButtons.indexOf(view);
}
```

But Android Studio keeps warning me about a `Suspicious call to 'ArrayList.indexOf'`.

Ok, I tried to get rid by casting `view` to `Button`.
Then the warning changed to `Casting 'view' to 'Button' is redundant`.

Well, I tried to change the function signature to receive a `Button` instead of a `View`.
But now I have one warning on each `Button` declaration (XML): `Method 'onButtonClick' on '...Activity' has incorrect signature`.

I'm really considering just add the `//noinspection SuspiciousMethodCalls` since it seems there's no workaround for it.

I would appreciate if anyone knows how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cast to `Button` the line before.

```
Button button = (Button) view;
int buttonIndex = mButtons.indexOf(button);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just as an extra answer, you just need to wrap the call in an instanceof check

```
if (view instanceof Button) {
    buttonIndex = mButtons.indexOf(button);
}
```

Basically the suspicious call is saying "There's no guarantee this is a valid object to look for"

(Sorry for the slow reply, I hit this thread when looking for an answer and I figured that providing an alternative solution would be the best)